# Trigger creation is not working

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have a problem related with the creation of a trigger on phpmyadmin.
I have a simple code like this one below that when I submit the code, returns me a sintax error in the line of the variable x declaration. I know that the SELECT query works because i've tested it, and return a string. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `after_assigntags_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `assigntags`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE x VARCHAR(10);
SET x = (SELECT UltLabel FROM assignlabels WHERE ALmessage=1);
INSERT INTO messages (Message) VALUES (x);
$$
END

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an syntax error,

`END` should come before your delimter `$$`.

Try something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `after_assigntags_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `assigntags`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE x VARCHAR(10);
SET x = (SELECT UltLabel FROM assignlabels WHERE ALmessage=1);
INSERT INTO messages (Message) VALUES (x);
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using `user variables`?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `after_assigntags_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `assigntags`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   SET @x = (SELECT UltLabel FROM assignlabels WHERE ALmessage=1 LIMIT 1);
   INSERT INTO messages (Message) VALUES (@x);
$$
END

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `BEGIN` comes after `DECLARE`

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `after_assigntags_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `assigntags`
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 
  x VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
  SET x = (SELECT UltLabel FROM assignlabels WHERE ALmessage=1);
  INSERT INTO messages (Message) VALUES (x);
  $$
END

DELIMITER ;
```